# Pass variable from another function parenthesis

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I want to use a variable in a function from another function parenthesis in javascript.

Here is my code:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div></div>
<button onclick = addindent('10px')>Click</button>
<button onclick = addindent('20px')>Click</button>
```

```
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
function addindent(px){
textarea.style.textIndent = px;   
}
.......
//hide a lot of codes

setInterval(function(){
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.textIndent = px;
//I want to use px here, but shows undefined
......
},1000)
```

I do hide a lot of codes and I can't assign the style for `div` in the `addIndent()` function because I do a a lot of other changes to 'div' in the `setInterval` function.

Do anyone know how to use the `px` in `addIndent` function from another function?

Comment: you could access the assigned px value using `textarea.style.textIndent`, or potentially use a global variable

Comment: it is a good way of doing it, but it doesn't help my situation:(

Answer (score 0):

That's an argument of that function so you can't use it from outside the function itself, what you can do is pass px as an argument to you other function as well or extract it to the outer scope

Comment: I has thought about passing px as an argument, but the px doesn't keep the same every time and i need to make several functions